# In Tastypie, why the password is not written in database when creating new user?

Tags: django, tastypie

I'm trying to create new users (+ their profile), and it seems to be good (response 201) but the password is empty on the database.

I have the following model:

```
class CliProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='cliuser')
    # other stuff
```

and the following resources:

```
class CliProfileResource(ModelResource):

    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user', full=True)

    class Meta(CommonResourceMeta):
        queryset = CliProfile.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'client_infos'
        fields = ['id']
        list_allowed_methods = ['post']


    def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
        '''
        We only need the email-adress to register a user. 
        '''

        ema = bundle.data['user']['email']
        usn = ema[:30] # Dirty, will be changed
        raw_pwd = mkpasswd() # Returns a 8 characters random password

        try:
            # Launches model validation
            User(username=usn, email=ema, password=raw_pwd).full_clean()
        except ValidationError as e:
            raise CustomBadRequest(
                code="wrong_user_infos_exception",
                message="Information is wrong as detailed: {0}".
                    format(e))
        else:
            bundle.data['user']['username'] = usn
            bundle.data['user']['password'] = make_password(raw_pwd)
            bundle = super(ClientInfoResource, self).obj_create(bundle, **kwargs)

        return bundle

     # The UserResource is not paste here, but it has nothing special (no override)
```

The data payload for the POST request is something as simple as:

```
data_post = {
        "user":{
            "email": "newuser@newuser.com",
        }
```

Another question. I have the feeling I'm doing things wrong since I suppose user creation should be in the UserResource, not in the CliProfileResource.
Indeed, I have BusinessProfileResource (linked to a user too), and I'll have to put the same user creation in this resource, which is NOT dry.
Is there a clean way to split: user creation in UserResource and cliprofile informations in CliProfileResource?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you can set the password this way. You either use `User.create_user(...)`, or create the user and then call `user.set_password`. Check out the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/)

Comment: make_password is in the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.hashers.make_password) and a blogger uses it [here](http://psjinx.com/programming/2013/06/07/so-you-want-to-create-users-using-djangotastypie/).
Compare to set_password(), you can use it independently from the User model.

Comment: sorry no. Haven't had the time to look into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason, it's because of the `fields` field of my UserResource that does not contain `password` in the allowed fields.
When I add it, it works.

Nevertheless, as it was a problem for the GET requests to have the password, that's why I overrided the `dehydrate()` method of UserResource then.

The working version is:

```
class Meta(CommonResourceMeta):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'users'
    fields = ['id', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'bizuser']
    detail_allowed_methods = ['get']
```

...

```
def dehydrate(self, bundle):
    '''Remove pwd from data bundle for obvious security purposes'''
    try:
        bundle.data.pop('password')
    except:
        pass
    return bundle
```